# Event Recevier ItemAdded/ItemUpdated and Custom Workflow with Word Automation Service

Tags: event-receivers, word-automation

I have created one visual webpart to convert selected word document to pdf using word automation service. Pdf is created successfully on each time when WAS timer job runs. I know we can not retain metadata while converting word to pdf using WAS. I created Event Receiver and Visual Studio Workflow on item added/updated. So i can copy word file metadata to pdf document. But neither ItemAdded/ItemUpdated events of Event Receiver fired nor workflow.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: If you are trying to debug an event receiver that is being triggered by a timer job, it will be called by the OWSTimer.exe, and not w3wp.exe. Not sure how workflow would be handled there.

Comment: Yes you are right i already tried it. I have attached debugger to OWSTimer.exe but still out of luck. Any other solutions?